# Qml window framelesswindowhint hide title

Tags: qml, window

I'm here for the first time, I'm a beginner . Help me clear up a problem. When I want to restore the window, top in the left corner appears the title. Please press the red button, then restore the window. Thank you for your help

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls



ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 700
    height:500
    color: "#00000000"

    flags: Qt.Window | Qt.FramelessWindowHint


    property alias windowBg: windowBg
    property alias btnMinimize: btnMinimize
    property alias btnMaximize: btnMaximize
    property alias btnClose: btnClose

    // Propeties
    property int windowStatus: 1
    property int windowMargin: 30

    // Internal functions
    QtObject{
        id: internal

        function resetResizeBorders(){
            // Resize visibility
            resizeLeft.visible = true
            resizeRight.visible = true
            resizeBottom.visible = true
        }

        function maximizeRestore(){
            if(windowStatus == 0){
                window.showMaximized()
                windowStatus = 1
                windowMargin = 0
                // Resize visibility
                resizeLeft.visible = false
                resizeRight.visible = false
                resizeBottom.visible = false
            }
            else{
                window.showNormal()
                windowStatus = 0
                windowMargin = 30
                // Resize visibility
                internal.resetResizeBorders()
            }
        }

        function ifMaximizedWindowRestore(){
            if(windowStatus == 1){
                window.showNormal()
                windowStatus = 0
                windowMargin = 30
                internal.resetResizeBorders()
            }
        }

        function restoreMargins(){
            windowStatus = 0
            windowMargin = 30
            internal.resetResizeBorders()
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: windowBg
        radius: windowStatus ? 0 : 6
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: windowMargin
        z: 1

        Row {
            id: rowBtns
            width: 105
            height: 35
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 0
            anchors.rightMargin: 20
            z: 1
            Button{
                id: btnMinimize
                width: 40
                height: width
                objectName: 'minimize'
                onClicked: {
                    window.showMinimized()
                    internal.restoreMargins()
                }
                background: Rectangle{
                    color: 'red'
                }
            }

            Button {
                id: btnMaximize
                width: 40
                height: width
                objectName: 'maximize'
                onClicked: internal.maximizeRestore()
                background: Rectangle{
                    color: 'green'
                }
            }

            Button {
                id: btnClose
                width: 40
                height: width
                objectName: 'close'
                onClicked: window.close()
                background: Rectangle{
                    color: 'yellow'
                }
            }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: resizeLeft
        width: 10
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        cursorShape: Qt.SizeHorCursor

        DragHandler{
            target: null
            onActiveChanged: {
                if (active) { window.startSystemResize(Qt.LeftEdge) }}
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: resizeRight
        width: 10
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 10
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        cursorShape: Qt.SizeHorCursor

        DragHandler{
            target: null
            onActiveChanged: if (active) { window.startSystemResize(Qt.RightEdge) }
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: resizeBottom
        height: 10
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.rightMargin: 10
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        cursorShape: Qt.SizeVerCursor

        DragHandler{
            target: null
            onActiveChanged: if (active) { window.startSystemResize(Qt.BottomEdge)}
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: moveWindow
        height: 40
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 0
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 10

        DragHandler {
            target: null
            onActiveChanged: if(active){
                                 window.startSystemMove()
                                 internal.ifMaximizedWindowRestore()
                             }
        }
        onDoubleClicked: internal.maximizeRestore()


    }

    Component.onCompleted:{
        internal.maximizeRestore()
    }
}
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDTBB.png)

I tried to look for some information on the forum, so and I did not find

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please clearly state what you are trying to accomplish and what  part you need help with.

Comment: in the picture "example" I drew an arrow to see what appears after I restore the window